# how to roll multiple, stand-alone AWS Lambda functions into a single SAM application build/deply script?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

What is the process to roll multiple existing local AWS Lambda Functions and 1 Step Function and a REST API Gateway (1 POST, 1 GET) into a single, *new* AWS SAM application, so they can more easily be built and deployed to AWS together?

Currently I have 5 different Lambda functions (`Foo1` ... `Foo5`) each developed locally (via Docker) in their own folders (foo1 ... foo5). When I change a function, I manually zip it and upload it to AWS Console. The Step Function and API Gateway were created and tested using AWS Console.

I avoided SAM **initially** (mainly due to the setup and learning curve, and relatively sparse documentation for a multiple-lambda setup).

But now that I have 5 working Lambda Functions (with test specs), and a working Step Function, and a simple API Gateway definition I'd like to streamline the build/deploy process by rolling all the parts into a single SAM application definition. (If I get *happen* to get local testing of the Step Function as part of the package, more's the better.

I've gone through a couple of basic single-lambda SAM tutorials, but can't quite get my head around how to roll multiple existing lambdas and a step function into a single new SAM application.

Any tips will be appreciated!

(The Lambdas, by the way, are implemented in Ruby although I doubt that impacts the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Example of using Step functions with multiple lambda functions is available part of AWS Quick start templates:

Try following steps using sam command line tool (I used version SAM CLI, version 1.21.1):

Run `sam init` from the command line. There will be several interactive questions:

1. Template Source - Choose option "AWS Quick start templates"
2. Choose Package type - Choose option "Artifact is a zip uploaded to S3"
3. Run time - Choose your language (I used python 3.x)
4. Project Name - Leave the default as sam-app
5. Quick start application  template - Choose option "Step Functions Sample App (Stock Trader)"

Sample application will be generated in the sam-app directory.

`cd sam-app`

You will find the sam template in template.yaml. State machine and lambda function definitions will be present inside the folder statemachine and functions.

Here is the github location for the ruby templates:https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates/tree/master/ruby2.7/cookiecutter-aws-sam-step-functions-sample-app

Similarly here is a simple hello world example for Lambda - API Gateway Integration https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates/blob/master/ruby2.7/cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-ruby/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/template.yaml

Other related references I found useful:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorials.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks @Shree that is a useful example of an existing template.yaml with multiple Lambdas. I am hoping for more of a guide to how to build the template.yaml (after the fact, from scratch given existing standalone resources). Some sort of magic "sam add-resource <folder>" command for example. But worst case, I can try use that as a guide to doing so manually, although there are some un-addressed complications such as how to handle a shared library source file, and sub-folders with utilities, and using already created IAM roles.